# Залипание клавиш програмное. Почему так происходит?

Tags: windows-10, клавиатура

Win 10

У меня примерно раз в неделю сходит с ума толи клавиатура, толи ОС, толи ещё что-то.
Я когда что-нить пишу вроде: "доброе утро" - получается:

добрррррррррррррррррррррррррррррррррррррррррррррррр... и так далее

Я понимаю что есть событие нажатия на клавишу и есть событие отпуска клавиши. И второе событие для ОС не срабатывает. Тут можно было бы и остановиться, но ПОЧЕМУ? :)

У меня USB - хаб, я просто на хабе кнопочку нажму для выключения клавиатуры, потом обратно и ОС приходит в норму.

Если кто-то даст адекватный ответ - буду признателен :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно методом исключения проверять:

1. Отключать/подключать хаб раз в три дня.
2. Подключить клавиатуру без хаба.
3. Поменять клавиатуру.
4. Поменять хаб.

Этого должно хватить для поиска и устранения неисправности.

Comment: В целом я так и делаю...)) Ну ладно, пусть будут приватности судьбы) Вопрос был почему... В любом случае на текущий момент я вернулся к ubuntu - тут таких проблем пока нет.